# SQL - Find value for the last 5 weeks and the next 5 weeks in the same query

Tags: sql, datediff

I need to find inventory values for the last 5 weeks and the next 5 weeks on any given day I run the query (going to connect to Excel and run daily).

I am able to find them individually but when done together I get no returns.

The following work individually, is there a way to combine and get all returns?

```
Select * FROM Table
WHERE vdvInventory.Count >= CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, -5, GETDATE()) as DATE)
```

alternatively

```
Select * FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(WEEK,vdvInventory.Count,GETDATE() )<5
```

If I try adding both where statements into one with an ADD I get no returns.
For Example:

```
Select * FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(WEEK,vdvInventory.Count,GETDATE() )<5
AND DATEDIFF(WEEK,vdvInventory.Count,GETDATE() )>5
```

Thanks for any help or guidance with this!

Comment: The first way could be to `UNION` the 2 first queries you mentioned. But the best way is to use window function (`PARTITION BY` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because you have a contradictory statement: same expression (`DATEDIFF(WEEK,vdvInventory.Count,GETDATE())`) cannot be less and greater than 5 at the same time.

Try instead the following:

```
Select * FROM Table
WHERE vdvInventory.Count >= CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, -5, GETDATE()) as DATE)
and vdvInventory.Count <= CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, 5, GETDATE()) as DATE)
```

Comment: I am still having issues with this.
I've tried the following:
`Select * FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(WEEK,vdvInventory.Count,GETDATE() )<5
union
Select * FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(WEEK,vdvInventory.Count,GETDATE() )>5
`
However this is giving me the next 5 weeks as needed but everything 5 weeks and beyond for the past. I am basically wanting a revolving 11 weeks that is run (previous 5 weeks, current, next 5 weeks). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MyOwnIssues just to make sure that I understand, lets say that the date today is 10/01/2021 and the period you search is 5 days (for simplicity). Do you want to get all the records with `vdvInventory.Count` between 05/01/2021 and 15/01/2021?

Comment: @MyOwnIssues please check my updated solution, it should work for you.

Comment: Gabip, you got it!!! Thanks and your assumption was correct. I am trying to figure out an inventory issue and this is what I needed.

Comment: @MyOwnIssues Happy to help!